# XML-RPC connection problem

Tags: python, xml-rpc

I have a simple xml rpc server running on a localhost. The server has the following address:
`servAddr = ("localhost", 8080)`. When I run the client on a different machine I get a `connection refused error`. However, when i change the line

```
servAddr = ("localhost", 8080)
```

to

```
servAddr = ("myhostname", 8080)
```

everything works fine...

Why ? And how to know hostname  in startup script for machine ?

Comment: try to use "0.0.0.0" as the hostname

Answer (score 0):

'localhost' refers to your local machine. It's an alias to 127.0.0.1 ip address. It only works when the server and the client are running on the same machine.

When you try to put the client on an other machine, localhost refer to the machine of the client --> no the machine of the server !

More information about localhost [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Answer (score 0):

localhost is a relative host name that (usually) always resolves to your local computer.  So when you're on a different computer and connecting to "localhost", you'll be attempting to connect to it, rather than your actual XMLRPC server.